# Get ID of post of new post added to firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the ID of the post recently sent to firebase

[image]

for example I want return the ID MYl69JC9vmx25q4ACWu

Here i

```java
    mFirebaseDatabase
        .getReference("Posts")
        .push()
        .setValue(post)
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            c -> {

               String postID = "" // get post id

              /** After adding a question a user should be taken to ViewQuestion Fragment  
               * pass the postID to the ViewQuestion Fragment


              */
              if (c.isSuccessful()) Toast.makeText(this, postID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            })
        .addOnFailureListener(
            e -> Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to do this by separating the call to `push()` (which is synchronous, and purely client-side) from the call to `setValue` (which actually sends the data to the server, and is asynchronous).

So:

```
val ref = mFirebaseDatabase
    .getReference("Posts")
    .push()

ref.setValue(post)
    .addOnCompleteListener(
        c -> {
           String postID = ref.key
           ...
```